# Is "stock progression" the common way to write about a set chord progression?

Tags: harmony

Moreover, would "stock progression" refer to a standard chord progression, say, I – VI – IV – V for a doo-wop song, or does it refer to a set form to write the harmony for a tune, adhering to the classical "rules" or harmony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say there are varying levels of naming.

*'Stock progression'* is just generic terminology, but the meaning is perfectly clear: commonly used progressions. Lots of synonymous terms are used like *harmonic formula*, *standard progression*, etc. Sometimes a specific term is used within a particular text like *schemata* which is used in *[Music in the Galant Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195313712).* This web site calls the common patterns *"[money chord](http://www.angelfire.com/fl4/moneychords/lesson.html)s."*

Some particular progressions are so commonly know they have their own generally universal names...

- 12 bar blues
- Rhythm changes
- La Folia
- etc. etc.

...there can be variations in these progression despite them being thought of as 'standard' progressions.

In reference to `I vi IV V` you could call it 'stock progression' or you could be more specific and say 'doo-wop progression.' Either way you will probably end up needing to list the chords whether for performance or analysis.

Comment: These answers are all very helpful, thank you so much! Can you clarify this + perhaps add it to your answer, please: would it then be wrong to think that a stock progression is *also* a "standard" way to write the harmony when the melody runs, say, B to C, if in C-maj. I.e. there are, if adhering to the rules of harmony, only a limited number of permutations of legitimate notes, and sometimes it helps memorising a common pattern, such that there are no parallel octaves, fifths, etc. This latter example is thus NOT a stock progression, whereas the great examples you showed, are. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

'*Stock progression*' is a way to talk about ***a*** standard chord progression, of which there are several - I v IV V, I vi ii V, 12 bar blues, Andalucian (Spanish) sequence, for example.

But it's pretty vague, as each needs  defining. As in 'It's a standard 12 bar in A', or it's 1950s doo-wop. But even that often isn't quite enough. What's a standard 12 bar? Does the 2nd bar stay on I or go to IV? Is doo-wop I vi IV V, or maybe I vi ii V?

So, it's a generic term, but a very vague one, hardly worth the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

It means a common chord progression.  Like the one you mention.  (Assuming you meant I, vi, IV, V.   A major VI would be rather less 'stock'.)

It's not a precise technical term, so don't over-analyse it.  There isn't just one 'stock progression' for any era or any style.

The term is used and illustrated quite well here:

http://openmusictheory.com/popRockHarmony.html

Comment: Like the one mentioned, but probably *not* the one mentioned. If someone said 'it's stock progression' to me, I wouldn't know which  'stock' it meant. 'Stock' in 60s rock is more likely 12 bar. Saying '50s doo-wop' *might* mean 1 6 4 5, or 1 6 2 5, although the Inkspots used a slightly different version!

Comment: @tim I think you're misunderstanding. You wouldn't be on a bandstand and have  someone say play the "stock progression," but they might say "12-bar blues," "rhythm changes," or "Montgomery-Ward bridge" - all of which are collectively known as "stock progressions."